# Multiple variables in multiple for loops in Go

Tags: go

I have two for loops with two different set of variables, where I also reuse one variable from one loop in the next. The code looks roughly like this:

```
func naive(z, x, y []uint32, n int) {
    var i, j, k int
    var A, B uint32

    for i = 0; i < n; i++ {
        B = 0

        for j = 1; j <= i; j++ {
            muladd(x[j], y[i - j], &A)
        }

        for k = 1; j < n; j++, k++ {
            muladd(x[j], y[n - k], &B)
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error message at the second for loop. It says `missing { after for clause`. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you increment both j and k on the last loop go doesn't like it

so try to change your code to

```
func naive(z, x, y []uint32, n int) {
    var i, j, k int
    var A, B uint32

    for i = 0; i < n; i++ {
        B = 0

        for j = 1; j <= i; j++ {
            muladd(x[j], y[i-j], &A)
        }

        for k = 1; j < n; j++ {
            muladd(x[j], y[n-k], &B)
            k++
        }
    }
}
```

pay attention to the last loop I just moved the `k++` statement inside the loop

Comment: Shouldn't `k++` be last in the block instead of first?